# How to asynchronously make micro service calls and map back to response object in Spring WebClient?

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I’m fairly new to reactive programming in Spring. In my application I need to make a DB call and then make 3 micro service calls to enrich the original data.

Once the DB call is complete, I can make all three requests in parallel. Each call works individually, but I’m confused on how to run the 3 API calls in parallel and stitch it all back to a Response Object.

```
OriginalData mainData = someDao.getAppData();
Mono<ReferenceData1> data1 = SomeClient.getData1(mainData);
Flux<ReferenceData2> data2 = SomeClient.getData2(mainData);
Flux<ReferenceData3> data3 = SomeClient.getData3(mainData);
// do some processing of the data
// zip all 4 objects together in a response object
```

I’ve been able to zip 2 fluxes back in a Flux object, but my goal here would be to return a Mono Response object that is made up of these 4 objects.

Any ideas on how to make this work, or any better suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: My recommendation would be "don't". Mainly: there is no guarantee the async operation will finish within the context of the HTTP request timeout. Have the HTTP response be a 201:Accepted, and have the client make new requests that query the database for current state. If they get partial data back, then they need to keep making the request until they get what they want, or you can make the API do that logic and return 404 until the database has the expected data.

Comment: I’m implementing this for a performance boost, so the timeout shouldn’t be a concern here.  It currently runs synchronously and returns to our UI

Comment: Sure, but let's say there is some exception within the `Flux` flow. How do you plan on capturing this without blocking at some level?

Comment: I would need to look into how to handle errors more as I go. But to start was hoping to just make some calls and stitch some data using this technique to get going

Comment: I would think the main point of using WebClient would be to make microservice calls async right? Essentially that’s all I want to do

Comment: WebClient can be synchronous, too, so no, that has nothing to do with the problem at hand. There is a [zip method](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#zip-java.util.function.Function-int-org.reactivestreams.Publisher...-), but you also need to think about exception handling with it, and it will return a Flux, not a Mono. You need to use collect methods to get a Mono